# getting the content type of the thing you searched in the display template

Tags: content-type, display-template

Basically what the title says I want to say what content type each search item is in the display template. How is this done???

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by updating the default item display template or make a copy of it and customize it based on your requirement.

**Make sure you map ContentType field in ManagedPropertyMapping** of display templates

some thing like below in your display template

```
&#39;Line 2&#39;{Line 2}:&#39;ContentType&#39;
```

Now in the html section you just append content type name contained in "line2" where ever you need. Like in below add a div next to oob elements

```
<div>_#= line2 =#_</div>
```